# Stripe payment splitting api

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-processing

i need bit clarification and guidance from exports about splitting stripe payment between multiple sellers.

I am building e-commerce systen and integrated stripe as a payment method for customers and it is working fine. Now I don't want to pay to manually to my sellers registered on my platform. I want to  split the payment between several accounts if possible.

Lets say my platform is charging 10% as commission to the sellers and the customer is buying to different items from 2 different seller that worth $1000 than I want to split the payment as follow internally

me $100
seller 1:$450
seller 2:$450

Any help or guidance will be appreciated thanks

Comment: https://support.stripe.com/questions/can-a-charge-s-funds-be-split-among-different-connected-accounts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stripe as such does not provide the splitting mechanism. But using Stripe Connect you can do it.

- In Stripe connect there is one main account called platform account and can have multiple secondary accounts connected to it. So in your case, your seller will connect with your platform account.
- Now for every charge you can split the amount among the seller and platform using **application_fee** parameter in charge object.

But this method has one problem also

- If the customer is purchasing from multiple sellers than you have to charge the customer many times(as no. of the seller). So in case of multiple items from different sellers I have used transfer API to transfer the amount to seller instead of multiple charging to customer

In my system, I also face the same problem and after a lot of research, I found this way working for me.

Comment: Exactly I have the same issue can you tell me how did you used this transfer API in your solution. We need to add the seller as our stripe customer or we need to connect sellers stripe account??

Comment: Used connected account to transfer the amount.

Comment: More details are [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/direct-charges#collecting-fees)

Comment: Hey @LavVishwakarma am I understanding it right that IF there's multiple sellers in questions, we have to use Separate charges and transfers? ie. Take payment on Platform account and then move it to multiple sellers via API?